# Test if there is more than 1 node with the same attribute XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

**A SAMPLE OF THE XML:**

```
    <course>
        <department code="VES">
            <dept_short_name>Visual and Environmental Studies</dept_short_name>
        </department>
        <course_group code="course_group1">Course Group 1</course_group>
        <title>Critical Media Practice: Non Fiction Filmmaking Workshop</title> 
    </course>

    <course>
        <department code="MAT">
            <dept_short_name>Mathematics</dept_short_name>
        </department>
        <course_group code="course_group1">Course Group 1</course_group>
        <title>Critical Media Practice: Non Fiction Filmmaking Workshop</title> 
    </course>

    <course>
        <department code="VES">
            <dept_short_name>Visual and Environmental Studies</dept_short_name>
        </department>
        <course_group code="course_group2">Course Group 2</course_group>
        <title>Critical Media Practice: Non Fiction Filmmaking Workshop</title> 
    </course>
    <course>
        <department code="VES">
            <dept_short_name>Visual and Environmental Studies</dept_short_name>
        </department>
        <course_group code="course_group1">Course Group 1</course_group>
        <title>Critical Media Practice: Non Fiction Filmmaking Workshop</title> 
    </course>
```

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO**

As you can see, department @code and course_group @code may vary on each course.
I want to select only those courses with the department code = "VES" and if they have more than one different course_group call a template

**TRIED THIS CODE BUT IT DOES NOT WORK**
note that I have a parameter call $department that it is already passing the 'VES' value. This parameter it is working, I am using it somewhere else with no problems. I tried the following code, but It calls the template many times, I need the template to be call only once if the condition is true.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="course[$department = department/@code]" group-by="course_group[@code]">
            <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) > 1">
                <xsl:call-template name="anchors"/>
            </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Consider to show us code samples of minimal input and corresponding output you want and the one you currently get to allow us to reproduce and understand the problem. As far as I can tell, for your snippets, assuming `$department` is `VES`, the for-each-group finds two groups, one with two members (grouping key `Course Group 1`) and the second group with one member (grouping key `Course Group 2`. So based on that information your named template should be called once, for the group with two members. With more data it could be called several times, for each group with more than one member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to select only those courses with the department `code = "VES"`
>   and if they have more than one different `course_group` call a
>   template

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:if test="
   distinct-values(/*/course[department
                       [@code eq 'VES']]
                           /course_group/@code
                   )[2]">
     <xsl:call-template name="myTemplate"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="myTemplate">
   myTemplate is called !
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<t>
    <course>
        <department code="VES">
            <dept_short_name>Visual and Environmental Studies</dept_short_name>
        </department>
        <course_group code="course_group1">Course Group 1</course_group>
        <title>Critical Media Practice: Non Fiction Filmmaking Workshop</title>
    </course>
    <course>
        <department code="MAT">
            <dept_short_name>Mathematics</dept_short_name>
        </department>
        <course_group code="course_group1">Course Group 1</course_group>
        <title>Critical Media Practice: Non Fiction Filmmaking Workshop</title>
    </course>
    <course>
        <department code="VES">
            <dept_short_name>Visual and Environmental Studies</dept_short_name>
        </department>
        <course_group code="course_group2">Course Group 2</course_group>
        <title>Critical Media Practice: Non Fiction Filmmaking Workshop</title>
    </course>
    <course>
        <department code="VES">
            <dept_short_name>Visual and Environmental Studies</dept_short_name>
        </department>
        <course_group code="course_group1">Course Group 1</course_group>
        <title>Critical Media Practice: Non Fiction Filmmaking Workshop</title>
    </course>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
   myTemplate is called !
```

**If now we just change**:

```
    <course_group code="course_group2">Course Group 2</course_group>
```

**to**:

```
    <course_group code="course_group1">Course Group 1</course_group>
```

**Then the result of the transformation is empty -- exactly as desired**.